# Binary Search Tree (BST) - array representations

Tags: arrays, sorting, tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I am trying to implement different types of array-based BST implementations. Namely, let's assume we have a tree like this:

```
      3
     / \
    1    5
   / \  / \
  0  2  4  6
```

Now, the above can be represented as a sorted array (Repr 1): `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`, as if we built the above tree using recursion and finding middle element in every step.

It can also be represented as a level-based tree, aimilar to what heap uses (Repr 2): `[3,1,5,0,2,4,6]`, with children of i at `2i+1` and `2i+2`.

I have some questions regarding building the above representations:

1. To convert a tree to Repr 1, we can use some form of in-order traversal algorithm. To build Repr 2, we can use BFS-based traversal. The reverse algorithms (from array to tree) are well-known. My questions is, how do I convert Repr 1 to Repr 2? I tried to approach it iteratively, but my main problem is finding out indices of children. I.e. root is at `n/2` but then how do I come up with formula for left/right child and process the rest of the array?
2. With Repr 1, is it possible to allow insertions? In simple recursive traversal we can find index of parent, but again, where should we insert the child (providing the array has free space to do so)

Comment: You have multiple questions here (how to create repr2 from repr1? Can we allow insertions with repr 1?). Can you focus on one question? As to your first question: as you have a way to create the tree from repr1, and you have a way to create repr2 from a tree, you really already have the answer to your question, no?

Comment: The children of node N are at 2N and 2N+1, N>0.

Comment: Are you talking about a [complete binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) and sift-up, O(log n)?

Comment: 2. I don't know if that is applicable to the question, but what's to stop you from just inserting at the appropriate array position? however, this is a good reason _not_ to represent a tree as an array because it's `O(n)`. _Cf_ B-trees, Red-Black trees, AVL trees, insert in `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

question 1: python implementation (i'm sorry i don't believe a specific language was chosen so i picked the one i'm most comfortable with)

```python
base_tree = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

trees = [base_tree]
repr_2 = []
while len(trees):
    tree = trees.pop(0)
    if len(tree)==0:
        continue
    middle = len(tree)//2
    repr_2.append(tree[middle])
    subtree1 = tree[:middle]
    subtree2 = tree[middle+1:]
    trees.append(subtree1)
    trees.append(subtree2)

print(base_tree)
print(repr_2)
```

question 2: i have no clue honestly